# Where should an `.htaccess` file be located?

Tags: .htaccess

I noticed that I had two `.htaccess` file on my website's server, one in the root folder, one in the `www` folder. Which one is active and which one should I delete?

Comment: ¿What's the root folder, `public_html?

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA it's the `/` one which contains `www` and a `.forward` file.

Comment: I meant in the system directory structure, not in the URLs.

Comment: Sorry @FelipeAlamedaA not sure if i understand, what is `public_html` I don't think I have such a folder?

Comment: It is usually the directory that holds the site in the web space. You can't see it as a directory with a browser, although you are inside it. But I realize your question has nothing to do with it, so my concern it's not relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You put the .htaccess in the folder whose behavior you want to alter.  This also affects the behavior of all the sub-folders.  It can happen that you want different behavior for one or more of the sub-folders in which case you give them their own .htaccess file and override the settings that are not to be inherited from the parent.